# how to solve the error "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'tuple' "

Tags: python, numpy

Sorry, I am new to python, I am trying to plot this function but it is telling me "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'tuple'
how do I change this to make the function work? "

```
def k(Tg, P):
return np.exp(((15-Tg)/P)-28795/4177.3)

a = (-100,-10,100,78,51)
b = (0.0236, 0.0237,0.0229, 0.00807, 0.0045)

erosion = k(a, b)
x = np.arange(0,365,1)
plt.plot(x, erosion)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make them NumPy arrays:

```
def k(Tg, P):
    return np.exp(((15-Tg)/P)-28795/4177.3)

a = np.array((-100,-10,100,78,51))
b = np.array((0.0236, 0.0237,0.0229, 0.00807, 0.0045))
```